# Definning a timerange with insights

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights, facebook-marketing-api

I'm attempting to retrieve the clicks and impressions in a time range for all campaigns. According to the documentation the following should work, but it returns everything unbound by date.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/act_560058834176764/campaigns?fields=id,name,insights.fields(clicks,impressions)&time_range[since]=2016-10-02&time_range[until]=2016-10-03&access_token=EAAWwyqCJfOkBAPYtFTXsh6JZBUWZCIsNaHTrLKpKVY2VmINwmZA8R8FPUpbe8rNU7nWRqXNrMlI0tMMrAjLrkzTMIfWSfu2DDn4YtauZBatQGhAKv2Raxd38d0Dj00O8sX9zHk5TwdtyPh0jxzW6cUdseg8Uah8LYqicaoaJA9QJVT0OCvEm
```

Any ideas? Do I have the format wrong or something?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following to get campaign level insights for certain time_range:

```
act_<ACCOUNT_ID>/insights?level=campaign&time_range={"since":"2016-10-02","until":"2016-10-03"}
```